# Too many processes have realtime or -20 niceness

Tags: audio, linux-mint, kde-4, pulse-audio, nice

For some reason a lot of my processes are real-time and and keep making my audio lag. Are these supposed to be real-time? I tried both a hard reboot and soft reboot, I even restarted pulse but to no avail.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by updating the offending processes via apt